# Umbraco 13 - Customized dictionary search

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I've created an Umbraco dictionary key and the integrated dictionary search bar only searches on the Umbraco key name and not on its values.

How can I extend this search to dictionary key values?

Example of a key created:
[image: key-crated-umbraco13]

Value research doesn't work:
[image: value-research]

Answer (score 0):

There's no out-of-the-box way to do it. But you should be able to implement your own so called "searchable tree" and have it replace the standard dictionary search. The docs aren't super detailed, but this should be a starting point: https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/extending/section-trees/searchable-trees